# Is it possible to retrieve Firebase ID Token from the CLI?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase function that is triggered `onRequest()`, using the `firebase-admin` SDK and using Express as middleware. This function is not expected to be tied to a Firebase client/frontend (meaning, it is expected that this function can be called via `curl -X POST ...` etc.).

I want to secure this function such that only users with access to the Firebase project can make requests. I've found [Firebase ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk), and see how to create them on the client side.

My issue is that I don't have a client to create them from.

**Is there a way to create an ID Token for an authorized user using the CLI, or another similar method?**

E.g., something like

```bash
firebase login
firebase use <project-id>
firebase generate-id-token // would return an ID token with standard expiration rules.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a command in Firebase CLI to login as a user and print ID token. You can call [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) using `cURL` and get the token.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[FIREBASE_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "email": "user@domain.tld",
  "password": "12345678",
  "returnSecureToken": true
}'
```

> I want to secure this function such that only users with access to the Firebase project can make requests.

Anyone can use the REST API but they must know the account's password to login.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. Just a quick follow-up: the `FIREBASE_API_KEY` you mention here is the Firebase project Web API Key, right? And this is a non-confidential key that does not need to be kept secret?

Comment: @SeanMcClure yes. It from the web config and not a secret

Comment: @Dharmaraj I tried your suggestion but got this error:  "message": "Requests from this iOS client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.". Any ideas?